# Azure Functions update keys at runtime every 30 minutes

Tags: azure-functions

In my project with Azure Functions, I retrieve a token from an identity server every 30 minutes. What I want to achieve is to save the new token in the configuration. So, in the `local.lsettings.json` I always have the latest valid token. I want to keep it simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we run the function locally, we will get the values from `local.settings.json`, if we run the function in Azure, we will get the values from `Application settings`.

Here I use c# as the sample, as these values are stored in system Environment, we can set the value like this

```
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("token", "token_value");
```

And we can get it like

```
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("token");
```

Comment: Thank you! It is working but now I don't know where the value is saved. I checked in the **Configuration** under the key and I found the old value.